# Laplace transformation questions

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}).$ Define the Laplace transformation $F:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$F(s)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt.$$ Then (part 1) $\lim_{s \to \infty}F(s)=0$ and (part 2), if $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, then $F(s)$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ for any $ a>b>0.$

Of course, my first jump at an answer for Part 1 is going to be \begin{align*} \lim_{s \to \infty} \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt &= \int_0^\infty \lim_{s \to \infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt \\ &= \int_0^\infty f(t)dt \lim_{s \to \infty}e^{-st} \\ &= 0*\int_0^\infty f(t)dt \\ \\ &\leq K*0 \\ \\ &= 0 \end{align*}

with $K=\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$ a finite real number. 
For part two we have that, for $K$ such that $f(t)\leq K$ a.e.,

\begin{align*} \frac{d}{ds}\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt &= \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{ds}f(t)e^{-st}dt \\ &= \int_0^\infty f(t)dt \frac{d}{ds}e^{-st} \\ &= \int_0^\infty -tf(t)e^{-st}dt \\  &\leq K\int_0^\infty | -te^{-st}| dt \\ &\leq \frac{K}{s^2} \end{align*}

so that $F'(S)$ exists and is finite almost everywhere.

Here's where I break down, but I took a stab at it anyway: Letting $a\leq x \leq b$ and assuming WLOG that $F(a)=0$ we have, \begin{align*} \int_a^x F'(s)ds &= \int_a^x \int_0^\infty -tf(t)e^{-st}dtds \\ &= \int_a^x \lim_{k\to \infty} \int_0^k -tf(t)e^{-st}dtds \\ &= \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_a^x \int_0^k -tf(t)e^{-st}dtds \\ &= \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^k \int_a^x -tf(t)e^{-st}dsdt \\ &= \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^k f(t) \int_a^x -te^{-st}dsdt \\ &= \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^k (e^{-xt}-e^{-at})f(t)dt \end{align*}

And I'm stuck at this point, not seeing how the goal of $F(x)$ can be reached and absolute continuity thus proven.

My biggest questions are whether, in part one and part two, the switch of the limit and the derivative under the integral sign is valid, and WHY are the valid if so (learning how to "take limits and differentiate under the integral sign" is one of my weakest points of analysis so far), and where to proceed in the second part of part two if my approach is valid to begin with.

Comment: This isn't really a complete answer, but I want to try and help (since I see no one is answering right away). Some of the main theorems dealing with Lebesgue integration as listed nicely [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Basic_theorems_of_the_Lebesgue_integral) deal with commuting the limit with an integral. I'm guessing for this case you can use the dominated convergence theorem since $f(t)e^{-st} \le f(t)e^{-t}$, granted you need to show that $f(t)e^{-t} \in L^1$ and a few other details, but I'm sure you can fill them in